# Scalar Functions Used Together Timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Using either of the following functions alone perform well (`dbo.getCorrectInventoryKey(Inventory_Key) and dbo.getEntityFullName2(Inventory_Key, '.')`), but when used together (`dbo.getEntityFullName2(dbo.getCorrectInventoryKey(Inventory_Key), '.')`) the query never returns...

```
CREATE    function [dbo].[getEntityFullName2] (@inventory_Key varchar(100),@delim varchar(5)) returns varchar(1000) as
begin

    declare
    @continue   bit,            /* loop controller */
    @dIndex     int,            /* delimeter index character position */
    @key        varchar(100),   /* temp var used to hold one key through the loop */
    @retStr     varchar(1000)   /* return string (full item name) */


    /* set the default values for our local variables */
    set @continue = 1
    set @dIndex = 0
    set @retStr = ''


    /* loop until we make it through all items in the key */
    while(@continue = 1) begin
        /* return the next index of the '-' character */
        set @dIndex = charIndex('-',@inventory_Key,@dIndex+1)

        /* if we didn't find another occurance, then we know we are done looping */
        if(@dIndex = 0) begin
            set @dIndex = len(@inventory_Key)
            set @continue = 0
        end

        /* set the current key value */
        set @key = left(@inventory_Key,@dIndex)
        /* check to see if we need to strip off a right '-' character */
        set @key = case right(@key,1) when '-' then left(@key,len(@key)-1) else @key end 

        /* concat our return string with the value from the DB */
        set @retStr = @retStr + isNull((select entity from dbo.tbl_Inventory_Entities where inventory_key LIKE (@key)),'[not defined]') + @delim
    end

    /* trim off the extra '-' character we inserted */
    set @retStr = left(@retStr,len(@retStr)-len(@delim))

    /* return the value */
    return @retStr 
end
```

and

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getCorrectInventoryKey](@key varchar(100))
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @returnkey varchar(100)

SELECT @returnkey = CASE
WHEN @key LIKE ('1001-2002-3003-4016%') OR @key LIKE ('1010-2002-3003-4016%') OR @key LIKE ('1020-2002-3003-4016%') THEN '1001-2002-3003-4016'
WHEN (@key LIKE ('1001-2002-3003-4005') OR @key LIKE ('1001-2002-3003-4006')) OR (@key LIKE ('1010-2002-3003-4005') OR @key LIKE ('1010-2002-3003-4006')) OR (@key LIKE ('1020-2002-3003-4005') OR @key LIKE ('1020-2002-3003-4006')) THEN '1001-2002-3003'
WHEN @key LIKE ('1001-2002-3004%') OR @key LIKE ('1010-2002-3004%') OR @key LIKE ('1020-2002-3004%') THEN '1001-2002-3004'
WHEN @key LIKE ('1001-2002-3005%') OR @key LIKE ('1010-2002-3005%') OR @key LIKE ('1020-2002-3005%') THEN '1001-2002-3005'
WHEN @key LIKE ('1001-2002-3007%') OR @key LIKE ('1010-2002-3007%') OR @key LIKE ('1020-2002-3007%') THEN '1001-2002-3007'
WHEN @key LIKE ('1001-2001-3001%') OR @key LIKE ('1010-2001-3001%') OR @key LIKE ('1020-2001-3001%') THEN '1001-2001-3001'
WHEN @key LIKE ('1001-2002-3006%') OR @key LIKE ('1010-2002-3006%') OR @key LIKE ('1020-2002-3006%') THEN '1001-2002-3006'
WHEN @key LIKE ('1001-2001-3020%') OR @key LIKE ('1010-2001-3020%') OR @key LIKE ('1020-2001-3020%') THEN '1001-2001-3020'
WHEN @key LIKE ('1003-2010%') THEN '1003-2010'
ELSE NULL
END

RETURN @returnkey

END
```

Comment: That's irrelevant because no matter the context it never returns, but use of the functions together is noted at the top... dbo.getEntityFullName2(dbo.getCorrectInventoryKey(Inventory_Key), '.')

Comment: Your use of these two functions on top of each other is likely to never produce a result. My guess if you let this run until the end of time it still wouldn't finish. You probably will want to re-think your entire solution. If that is not an option you may want to try executing the first function into a table and then running the second function on that result set. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Holy cow, I can't see why this question was voted closed.  Perfectly reasonable question, and enough details were provided.  One possible answer is below.

Comment: @KevinSuchlicki my assumption is it's too localized.

Comment: @Zane The message I see is "closed as not a real question." But thanks for offering a possible explanation. I guess it is fairly narrow, but only slightly more so than most of the application-specific questions on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your function getCorrectInventoryKey is returning non-null values in every case?  It looks like it is at least *possible* that it is returning a NULL (base on the ELSE clause of the CASE statement), in which case your function getEntityFullName2 will enter an infinite loop.  If @inventory_Key parameter is NULL, then

```
set @dIndex = charIndex('-',@inventory_Key,@dIndex+1)
```

will set @dIndex to NULL and the following code will not execute:

```
if(@dIndex = 0) begin
    set @dIndex = len(@inventory_Key)
    set @continue = 0
end
```

Change

```
set @dIndex = charIndex('-',@inventory_Key,@dIndex+1)
```

to

```
set @dIndex = ISNULL(charIndex('-',@inventory_Key,@dIndex+1), 0)
```

Comment: *face palm*  Thank you!

Comment: LOL, it's happened to all of us.